# Jquery validation addMethod to over ride default for url field

Tags: jquery, validation

I want to turn off Jquery's validation on a url input field - [example here](http://webconsultant.co.nz/question/form-validation.html)

I've added a method which I call on both a text field and a url field, but with with different results. Jquery's validation of a url field wins out over mine, but I don't want `http://` in the URLs I collect.

Is there a way to make mine take over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could override the default url validation of jquery validate like:

```
jQuery.validator.methods.url = function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || true;
};
```

and then add your custom url validation method:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("isurl",function(value,element) {
  return this.optional(element) 
     || /^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/.test(value); 
},"Proper URL, please");
```

Comment: Perfect.  That's the answer, thank you very much.  I had tried for a whole day to find that one

Comment: you're welcome.. you might considering accepting the answer if it worked for you.. :)